# asp.net sessions issue

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem of the session not expiring. Here is my case

I have a application in asp.net1.1. i am able to handle session when user click logout button. Session is active for 35 minutes. the application is also check if same user is trying to login using multiple machine and blocks it.

Now this application is deployed in city where there is power outage. When user is loggd in and light goes off,  the session remain open. Due to this, the user is not able to log in again for next 35 minutes from alternate machine.

Can you tell solution of how to handle issue of session remained open the right way?

Answer (score 2):

Did you write the code that if a session already exists, refuse another login?  If so, you will probably have to change it.  It is more common to kill the old session and start a new one if necessary.  I prefer to allow multiple sessions for a single user unless there is some specific security requirement not too.

Comment: Since this is a web application and not a client application the normal design would be to log out the old session when the user logged in the second time.

Comment: Can you share code please..how to detect old session and start new one in asp.net1.1? also how will it work in IE8 with new session feature?

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the SessionState timeout field in Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to add UPS to the client workstations so they don't lose the connection if the power goes out.  The only other option I can think of in this situation is to add something to the login code which, instead of blocking an alternate location login, instead forces the other session to be expired on a successful login.

Answer (score 0):

We solved some similar issue this way:

in the body of the asp.net page, we attach on the onload event an ajax call. In this ajax call, the session timeout is set to 35 mins.

Also an ajax call is attached to the onunload, where we set the session timeout to 1 min.

This way the user has 35 min timeout when using the application, yet has 1 minute timeout when closing the application.